# Merge tags [hp-quality-center], [quality-center], [qc], and 2 more

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, retag-request, synonym-request

These tags refer to [the](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/hp-quality-center/info) [same](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/quality-center/info) [thing](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/qc/info): HP Quality Center. They should be merged into one / have the others be synonyms for **[hp-quality-center](/questions/tagged/hp-quality-center)** aka HPQC, which is the least ambiguous, though not historically accurate (see item #4 below).

- [quality-center](/questions/tagged/quality-center) has 109 questions, created 2 years ago
- [hp-quality-center](/questions/tagged/hp-quality-center) has 60 question, created 2 months ago
- [qc](/questions/tagged/qc) has 85 questions, created 2 years ago
- [testdirector](/questions/tagged/testdirector)  [also exists](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/testdirector/info) with just 5 questions - Mercury's Test Director was bought by HP and re-branded to Quality Center. (And to-date, we still see 'TDD' in the APIs.)

HP Application Lifecycle Management (ALM; *terrible name*) v11, which just happens to be the one to come after Quality Center 10, includes Quality Center as well some other enterprise tools. If `[hp-alm]` or `[hpqc]` tags get created in the future, those should also point to [hp-quality-center](/questions/tagged/hp-quality-center) - in the context of StackOverflow questions, those would be the same as HPQC.

Comment: `[qc]` should be burninated, not merged into these.  It's a common abbreviation for "quality control" and is used that way on a non-trivial number of questions.

Comment: quick browse of all the questions on SO tagged [qc] currently - all refer to quality center, so someone using that tag should see it. anyway, there's already a [qa] tag pointing to [quality-assurance]. can't really prevent people from using the wrong tag but hey, that's what edits are for :-)

Comment: All?  No.  [qc+testing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qc+testing), [qc+qa](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qc+qa), [qc+defects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qc+defects), [qc+automated-tests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qc+automated-tests).  Some in there have no relation to HP Quality Center, but most do.  It's *still* ambiguous and should not be included as a synonym here.  It should be burninated.

Comment: All minus 2. And those two have the [qa] tag as well. Like I said, can't stop people from using the wrong tags. Everything else mentions terms like 'test plan', 'test lab' which are HPQC related. Along with QTP, ALM, etc. So those should be synonym-ed to [hp-quality-center] before deleting or blacklisting [qc].

Comment: I've [copied this question over to meta.SO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272331/merge-tags-hp-quality-center-quality-center-alm-and-2-more). Should have been migrated, instead of closing, like [this newer identical question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250928/is-there-a-way-to-delete-merge-duplicate-tags) was.